# Android trouble in proceeding the activity

Tags: java, android-activity

I am new to Android  development. I have seen a few tutorials and some textual references also. So I have a basic idea of Android. I am currently facing a problem while writing the JAVA code. I am unable to grasp the concept of what should be my next step while writing the code. Eg. I want to create an application for online attendance. I decided to have a text box for roll number and a 'submit' button to submit the attendance. Now in my Main.java file , after creating a button object, I am not following what my next step should be. 
Similar situations arise when I try to make a jump from one page to another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have managed to add a click listener to the button so, now you have to use [intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) to transition between activities.